# ES6 destructuring two objects with same property name

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

i have two javascript object with the next syntax:

```
let section = { name: "foo", tables: [] }
let field   = { name: "bar", properties: {} }
```

and a function who expect those objects, but in the function i only use the name of each object, so i wanted to know if i can destructuring the two objects in the function's declaration like:

```
function something( {name}, {name} ) {
  //code
}
```

the first should be `section.name` and the second should be `field.name`.

Is there a way two do a destructuring in this scenario? or should i spect only the names in the function?

Which is better?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried? Was there an error?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the name property for each of the two parameters if that's all that is used?  Why use destructuring at all?

Comment: Of course, since the same are called name it retrieves: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Duplicate parameter name not allowed in this context

Comment: You can rename deconstructed variables, like `something({name: sectionName}, {name: fieldName})`

Comment: Yep the second option is only pass the name property and name the vars different, but i wanted to know if there is a way of destructuring two properties with same name, it lloks like Andy has answered my question, thank you all

Comment: yeah thank you i tried but Stack give me the message 'You have to wait 2 minutes' xD sorry

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yup, it looks like you can label/reassign the parameters: `{before<colon>after}`

```js
var section = { name: 'foo', tables: [] };
var field = { name: "bar", properties: {} };

function something({ name: sectionName }, { name: fieldName }) {
  console.log(sectionName, fieldName);
}

something(section, field);
```

Comment: +1, but in production please use some more meaningful names. `something({ name: sectionName }, { name: fieldName })`.

Comment: Of course no one would use foo or bar. Your comment is overly pedantic.